# Form closing immediately after show in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having a bit of trouble with a form it's a form designed with the form designer and my project, it closes immediately upon showing. Here's the relevant code:

```
namespace Grapher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InputForm mainForm = new InputForm();
            mainForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to put in a for(;;) but that just makes the for hang, I'm probably doing something silly, very new to C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is more than one thing wrong with your Main() method.  It has a critical bug that will make your life miserable with random and unexplainable exceptions.  Use the version that's pre-generated by the project template, don't write your own until you *really* know what you are doing.

Comment: This was actually generated by the console application project, but could you point it out to me?

Comment: Then why are you running a WinForm?

Comment: I'm trying to have an SFML.NET window in tandem with a WinForm.

Comment: Create a Winforms project, copy and paste the Program class.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all of your help, I do have a lot of code in this project, though. The form being the least of it. It'd be a bit of a pain to get all this set back up.

Comment: `Application.Run` is required because it contains a message loop. A message loop is a loop that retrieves messages from the operating system and redirect to the relevant controls. Without the loop, your application exists immediately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Application.Run()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902.aspx):

```
namespace Grapher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Run(new InputForm());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this give control to the Form as far as flow goes?

Comment: If you mean that the form's code will run according to that, then yes. The constructor is run, i.e. where `InitializeComponent` is called, and then a bunch of event handlers run, the most relevant being `Form.Load`. When that form is closed, control will be returned to the `Main` method.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
Application.Run(mainForm);
```

This will start the UI properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Application.Run(new InputForm())`.

Your code simply shows the form, then the program reaches its end (the end of the `Main` function) and terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem using `form.ShowDialog()` instead of `form.Show()`